# Как получить width для слова на html страничке?

Tags: javascript, html

Как получить width для слова на html страничке?

Answer (score 2):

Например, поместить текст в div с `width: auto;` и потом взять его (div'a) `clientWidth`.

Div'у через css задаем нужный размер и стиль шрифта (можно динамически js'ом).

http://jsfiddle.net/9hFN4/

Еще можно нарисовать на canvas, но по-моему с div'ом проще будет.

Comment: Дело в том, что из за особенностей среды в которой разработано приложение, div не расстягивается на ширину текста который находится в нем, а все время равен ширине ячейки - (4-6px), в случае если ширина текста больше ширины div-а, то текст в ячейки находится не весь.

Comment: Ну так не нужно <div> помещать в ячейку. Можно, например, разместить его сразу в <body>. А можно его вообще создавать динамически http://jsfiddle.net/9hFN4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Слово можно поместить в тег [span](http://htmlbook.ru/html/span), так как он предназначен для оформления строчных элементов. А Для получения ширины элемента можно использовать свойство [.offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('word').offsetWidth);
```

```html
<span id="word">Слово</span>
```